# Starting from scratch with firefox, but keeping some stuff

Tags: macos, firefox

I run Firefox 3.6 on OS/X. My Profile, along with saved passwords, bookmarks and history has come along with me across 3 different computers, and has been upgrading since 2.0, has had hundreds of addons installed, updated and removed and has even seen some Minefield builds.

Not completely surprising, my firefox seems sluggish. I'd like to start from scratch with a clean profile, but I can't do this without my history, bookmarks and saved passwords.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [FEBE (Firefox Environment Backup) extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/). You can back up the whole profile, uninstall and then reinstall a clean Firefox. Then restore the elements that you want to transfer.

I think it's available with OS X, but the homepage is down so I can't confirm.

[image]

Comment: As an update, I actually just copy-pasted the files instead. The extension is rather convoluted, and this proved to be much easier.

Comment: OK. Feel free to unaccept the answer (if that's possible). Personally, I haven't found the extension to be convoluted, but it's your question! Good luck with whatvever method you go with.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Managing Multiple Firefox Profiles in OS X](http://spf13.com/feature/managing-firefox-profiles-os-x) -- as the title implies, it's mostly about having multiple profiles. However, the key thing is that it shows you how to launch the profile manager. From there, you can create a new profile and nuke your old one.

Answer (score 1):

And once you've created a new profile, you can move your information over in a couple of ways.

For bookmarks, you can export then import; for other files, firefox stores the data in sqlite files.  You should be able to copy over these files from your old profile directory (one at a time to verfiy they have the data you're expecting).  Just make sure that FF is not running when you copy them over.